# How to make table with row name and column name

Tags: mysql, php

I am new to databases and now i came to a point where i need more complex table.
I have a table which contains site details. Each site can have multiple devices. Each device have multiple measurement tables.

Structure looks like this:

```
                    DEVICE LIST TABLE 1 ► MEASUREMENT TABLE (each device)
SITE LIST TABLE ►   DEVICE LIST TABLE 2 ► MEASUREMENT TABLE (each device)
                    DEVICE LIST TABLE 3 ► MEASUREMENT TABLE (each device)
```

Measurement table looks like this

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|    | F1 | t1 | F2 | t2 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A1 |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A2 |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A3 |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A4 |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A5 |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A6 |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I do not understand how to make table like this. If not possible what is the best practice to link every `ROW` with device.

Or should i create dynamically measrements A1 to An?

```
+-----------+---------+----+----+----+----+
| device_id | name    | F1 | t1 | F2 | t2 |
+-----------+---------+----+----+----+----+
|           | A1...An |    |    |    |    |
+-----------+---------+----+----+----+----+
```

And then do

```
SELECT * FROM measurement_table WHERE device_id = x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should revise your table structure. 
You are trying to put too many different things into one table.

What you could do is have multiple tables like so:

Table: site
Has an ID and all other details about the site! 
Table: Devices
Has an ID and all other details about the device. 
Table: measurements 
Has an ID and all other details about the measurement.

Now depending on if your measurements are linked to a single device or not you may need an intersection table or a device ID on the measurement,  and the same goes for the site.

When you wish to select all the details about a site,  you will need to use joins to get everything,  or maybe multiple queries.